# Freeware software to view gps data

Tags: windows-7, gps

I'm looking for some freeware software to view gps data with.  In particular I'm interesting in something that can keep track of my walking, cycling and driving separately and display graphs/summaries of average speeds and distance travelled.  (Windows 7)

Comment: Are you considering buying a GPS device or using a smartphone/pocket PC?

Comment: I've already got a GPS - I have used GPSBabel to transfer the data to my PC.

Comment: What format is the GPS data in?

Comment: Daisetsu - The GPS data can be in lots of formats, including gpx. See http://www.gpsbabel.org/capabilities.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may give **[SportTracks](http://www.zonefivesoftware.com/SportTracks/)** a shot. It's freeware.

> Coupled with a GPS receiver
>   SportTracks will automatically track
>   the distance, time and pace of your
>   workouts. You'll be able to take a
>   high level view and track your
>   progress over time, or dive into the
>   details of a specific exercise to
>   analyze your pace, elevation, or
>   heart-rate performance. Activities can
>   be organized into categories, or
>   summarized by location.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is great web application.

SportyPal - http://sportypal.com

- support for upload log from GPS in GPX format